# Class structure/dynamic array

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I just recently switched from C++ over to Fortran. As you would probably guess, I am having some syntax growing pains.

What I am trying to accomplish is define a class with dynamic arrays. I then need to pass a class variable to a subroutine, but I can't figure out how to declare (is that the right word here? I am still thinking in C++), the arrays in the subroutine.

Here are the portions of my code that are applicable.

```
  program lennard

  implicit none

  type list

     integer :: M,ncell                                      !! m is number of cells per dimension. ncell is the total number of cells
     double precision :: rn                                  !! length per dimension of cell
     double precision, allocatable :: HOC(:), ll(:),nlist(:)
     double precision, allocatable :: verlet(:,:)

  end type list

  type(list) :: listvar
  double precision, allocatable :: x(:), y(:), z(:)
  integer :: N


  allocate (x(np),y(np),z(np))

  listvar%rn    = box/int(box/rcut)
  listvar%ncell = vol/(listvar%rn**3)
  listvar%M     = listvar%ncell**(1.0/3.0)
  allocate (listvar%HOC(listvar%ncell), listvar%ll(np), listvar%nlist(np))
  allocate (listvar%verlet(np,np))

stop 

end program lennard
```

and here is the subroutine

```
  subroutine nlist(np,x,y,z,listvar)

  implicit none

  type list

    integer :: M,ncell     !! m is number of cells per dimension. ncell is the total number of cells
    double precision :: rn !! length per dimension of cell
    double precision :: HOC(:), ll(:),nlist(:)
    double precision :: verlet(:,:)

 end type list


  integer :: i
  integer :: icel, M,ncell
  integer :: np
  type(list) :: listvar
  double precision :: x(np),y(np),z(np)
  double precision,allocatable :: listvar%ll(np),x(np),y(np),z(np)
  double precision,allocatable :: listvar%HOC(listvar%ncell)


do i=1,ncell
   listvar%hoc(i)=0.0
enddo

do i=1,np
   icel = int(x(i)/listvar%rn)+M*int(y(i)/listvar%rn)+M*M*int(z(i)/listvar%rn)
   listvar%ll(i) = listvar%hoc(icel)
   listvar%hoc(icel) = i
enddo


return

end subroutine nlist
```

Comment: I am trying to create a linked list for a monte carlo simulation. List var should contain all the information needed for the variables in list. For instance, I want it to contain the number of cells in the simulation ncell, length of a cell(rn), number of cells per dimension (M), and the arrays head of chain (HOC) which contains the pointers to the linked list (ll). I want to create the linked list in subroutine nlist

Comment: This possibly isn't the best way to go about a linked list, but that's a whole new question.

Comment: You've tagged as fortran90, but you're not limited to that old standard?

Comment: My current issue is that all the arrays I mentioned need to be dynamic arrays. So I don't know how to tell the subroutine the size of the arrays in listvar

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before coming to answer what I think is your question, I'll note something.  The type `list` in the subroutine and the type `list` in the program are *not* the same thing, even though they have the same name and components.  Instead, you'll want just one type definition.  As subroutine `nlist` is not internal to the program you do this with a module, which you then `use` in your program.

Further, you may want to put the subroutine `nlist` also in this module (after a `contains`) as this is an easy way to make an explicit interface for it available to the program.  If you don't have `nlist` in the module then you'll need to `use` the module there, too.

With that out of the way

```
double precision,allocatable :: listvar%ll(np),x(np),y(np),z(np)
double precision,allocatable :: listvar%HOC(listvar%ncell)
```

makes no sense.  You don't need to declare the components once you have the type definition.  Indeed, it's erroneous to and the `allocatable` attribute has to be given in the type definition, just like you had in the program.  In addition, you've already declared `x`, `y` and `z` in previous lines.  [Note also that unless you are doing things with the allocation status of these variables they needn't be declared with the `allocatable` attribute.]

You have a module, then, like:

```
module listmod
  implicit none

  type list
    integer :: M,ncell
    double precision :: rn !! length per dimension of cell
    double precision, allocatable :: HOC(:), ll(:),nlist(:)
    double precision, allocatable :: verlet(:,:)
  end type list

 contains

   subroutine nlist(np,x,y,z,listvar)
     ! Declarations for np, x, y, z
     type(list), intent(inout) :: listvar ! A sensible assumption of intent

     ! Declaration of local variables
     ! Work
   end subroutine
end module
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it without a module? How does the subroutine know the size of the dynamic arrays that are members of the class list?

Comment: You _want_ to do it with a module.  When there is the explicit interface (and the single defined type), it's the job of the compiler to ensure it knows the size of the arrays.

Comment: so when I allocate the arrays in my main (sorry still thinking in c++) program, all other subroutines will then know the size of the arrays upon subsequent calling?

Comment: Correct.  When a type variable is passed around all information about it goes with it (except when it is passed as `intent(out)`).  This includes sizes of components (and lots of other things in more complicated cases).

Comment: Awesome! one last question. If subroutine nlist took as an argument a variable of a class type defined in a seperate module, would that be in an issue? In c++, I would just #include the other header file or forward declare the class type, but not sure about here.

Comment: `use` is again your friend in this case.

Comment: Is is possible to declare the subroutine in the module, and have the actual code in another .f90 file like in c++? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: The module can contain all your "actual code".  If that isn't what you meant, then after suitable time researching feel free to ask another question.